# how to edit country and keyboard in windows 11 iso

Tags: windows, iso-image, editing

I have used Rufas to make windows 11 iso but when it boots up it still is prefilled with United States region and United States keyboard and i need to select and change to UK. How can I modify the iso so that these are all prefilled with UK and not United States.thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: ok i think i found it all in ntlite....i am trying now..thanks